# В Firefox после последнего обновления подключаемые шрифты стали кривыми

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Делал давно уже сайт http://corepro.kz/ на сайт подключил семейство шрифтов myriad pro подключал их через фйайлы формата otf и подключал вот так:

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: myir;
 src: url(fonts/Semibold.otf);
 }
```

ну и присваивал их в нужные места вот так

```
 font-family: myir;
```

но после последнего обновления Огне-Лиса они стали "кривфми" как буд то сглаживание пропало - при том в Хроме все отображается корректно? Кто нибудь уже сталкивался с таким? Реально откурываю в 2х разных браузерах шрифты смотрятся по разному!

Comment: А где именно проблема в каких местах? если в тех, где используется изначально стиль bold, то нужно указывать font-weight: 100. Т.к. FF прикручивает на bold свое видение bold *) сталкивался с таким же.
Это "до": http://prntscr.com/a6kj0c
Это "после": http://prntscr.com/a6kjvf

Comment: Вот еще полезно почитать: http://blog.wax-o.com/2012/11/font-face-rendering-problem-in-chrome-and-firefox-use-postscript-outlines/

Comment: спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что браузеры по разному отрисовывают шрифты. Между прочим, у вас зачем то два раза происходит объявление шрифта `myir` в css-коде вот так:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myir';
    src: url('des/Semibold.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'myir';
    src: url('des/MyReg.otf');
}
```

Для себя я проблему решил бы приблизительно так (хотя я бы не использовал их вообще). Шрифт `Semibold.otf`  в файрфоксе выгляди очень толстенько. Поэтому хрому отдаем шрифт `Semibold.otf`, а файрфоксу отдаем шрифт более тонкий шрифт `MyReg.otf`. Делаем это так, теперь в хроме и файрфоксе выглядят приблизительно одинаково:

```
/* для всех браузеров */
@font-face {
font-family: 'myir';
src: url('des/Semibold.otf');
}

/* для файрфокса */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'myir';
    src: url('des/MyReg.otf');
  }

}
```

Comment: такое решение помогло спасибо, не идеал конечно но что то уже прилично смотрится) возможно просто стоит шрифт выкинуть этот и нормальны поставить)

Answer (score 0):

Можно включить сглаживание, попробуйте это

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: попробовал, но что то все равно не на всем сайте помогло) спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Поставьте так 
font-family: Semibold;

Comment: это не много улучшило но все равно в Хроме Condent Bold и Semibold шрифты на много четче и даже жирнее чем в Фоксе\

Answer (score -1):

```
@font-face {
font-family: myir;
src: url(des/Semibold.otf);
}

@font-face {
font-family: Semibold;
src: url(des/Semibold.otf);
}
```

Убрать

```
@font-face {
font-family: myir;
src: url(des/Semibold.otf);
}
```